# Merging two columns from two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have to merge two columns from two unrelated tables with the same number of rows in another table, like

Table A:

```
AColumn
 'ABC'
 '152'
 'XXX'
```

Table B:

```
BColumn
  'FF'
  'CD'
  '91'
```

Expected result for the destination table (table C):

```
CColumn1    CColumn2

 'ABC'        'FF'
 '152'        'CD'
 'XXX'        '91'
```

Apparently this looks very simple but I can't find a way to achieve it.

My attempt would be something like:

```
SELECT A.AColumn as CColumn1, B.BColumn as CColumn2 into C
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON 1=1
```

but this obviously generates all the possible combinations over the elements, while I just want the first row from A matched with the first row from B, the second row with the second row, etc.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a row_number to each table and join on that, here is an example using two CTEs:

```
with a as (
     select AColumn, row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn
     from Table1
 ),
b as (
     select BColumn, row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn
     from Table2
 )
 select a.AColumn, b.BColumn
 from a full outer join b
     on a.rn = b.rn
```

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/291c7/4